# Is there a good code for drawing trajectory, fast?

Tags: matlab, plot

Input data is as follows:

```
X = [x1,y1,z1; x2,y2,z2; ...; xn,yn,zn];
```

My drawing code is as follows:

```
for i=1:size(X,1)-1
    plot3([X(i,1),X(i+1,1)],[X(i,2),X(i+1,2)],[X(i,3),X(i+1,3)],'-k')
end
```

The size of X is around 100000 by 3.
Hence, the above code is very very very slow.
Is there a way to boost up drawing trajectory?

---

I guess my code is slow because of super many iterations.
I hope a code using one-shot plot function, or small number of usage of plot functions.

Comment: This code will crash in the end since you iterate `i` to `size(X,1)` but in your loop you request `X(i+1,1)`. It will exceed the size of X.

Comment: @Gelliant Yes, you are right. The right code must be `i=1:size(X,1)-1`. The above code is thoughtlessly typed just for explaining the concept of my code. Thank you for noticing me, and I edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
plot3(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3),'k')
```

this plots all the rows at once, where the x-coordinates are defined by `X(:,1)`, y-coord by `X(:,2)` and z-coord by `X(:,3)`.